# Filtering multiple data frames based on the values in a common variable and saving them as different data frames

Tags: r, for-loop, filter, group-by

I have three data frames each including a column named "center". In this column there are 6 different values based on which I need to group data and save them as different data frames. Below you can see an example of one data frame. The other two data frames vary in the number of columns and rows. But the columns center and NR (being the unique ids) are common across all of them.

```
structure(list(NR = c("DBD-0006", "DBD-0057", 
"DBD-0095", "GHP-0169", "GHP-0237", "NNB-0243", "NNB-0303", 
"NNB-0306", "NNB-0359", "NNB-0364"), DATE = c("13-07-2011", 
"15-12-2010", "09-03-2011", "14-09-2011", "30-06-2010", "16-05-2016", 
"04-07-2012", "11-07-2012", "05-12-2012", "12-12-2012"), CODE= c("1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), DATE2 = c("18-07-2011", 
"15-12-2010", "09-03-2011", "14-09-2011", "05-01-2012", "11-05-2016", 
"05-07-2012", "11-07-2012", "06-12-2012", "12-12-2012"), type = c("YY.90.01", 
"50.19", "50.37", "50.37", "50.37", "YY.90.00", 
"50.37", "YY.50.01", "YY.82.01", "YY.50.02"), center = c("DBD", 
"DBD", "DBD", "GHP", "GHP", "NNB", "NNB", "NNB", "NNB", 
"NNB")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I have tried to use a loop to filter the data but it does not work. Could you please help me with that? Any other solution that is neater than using a for loop is also highly appreciated.

what I did was to create a list containing the three data frames and called it **cnt**.
cnt includes df1, df2 and df3 on the first level. Then each df has its own variables including "center" and "NR". So I think we can call it a nested list. This is how my loop looks like.

```
output <- list ()    

for (table in names(cnt)) {                  #print(table)  df1, df2, df3
  for (name in names(cnt[[table]])) {          #print(name)  returns the variable names per df
    center_name <- c("DBD", "GHP", "NNB")    
    output[[table]] <- cnt[[table]][[name]] %>% filter(center == center_name)     
  }
}
```

Here is the error I get.

```
  Error in UseMethod("filter") : 
  no applicable method for 'filter' applied to an object of class "character"
```

It seems that I can't assign the right data to filter.

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but did u load the dplyr package via library(dplyr). I remember a similar error message when I did not load the library properly.

Comment: @szmple Yes, I just double checked it.

Comment: I can't reproduce your error from the code you provided

Comment: Is there another package attached with function named `filter`? Try `dplyr::filter(center == center_name)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first `ls` with a `pattern`to get the names,

```
df_names <- ls(pattern='df\\d$')
```

use `mget` piped into `setNames` to get a named list,

```
cnt <- mget(df_names) |> setNames(df_names)
```

finally `split` on `$center` which gives you a list with the result.

```
res <- lapply(cnt, \(x) split(x, x$center))

str(res)
# List of 2
# $ df1:List of 3
# ..$ DBD:Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  6 variables:
#   .. ..$ NR    : chr [1:3] "DBD-0006" "DBD-0057" "DBD-0095"
# .. ..$ DATE  : chr [1:3] "13-07-2011" "15-12-2010" "09-03-2011"
# .. ..$ CODE  : chr [1:3] "1" "1" "1"
# .. ..$ DATE2 : chr [1:3] "18-07-2011" "15-12-2010" "09-03-2011"
# .. ..$ type  : chr [1:3] "YY.90.01" "50.19" "50.37"
# .. ..$ center: chr [1:3] "DBD" "DBD" "DBD"
# ..$ GHP:Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  6 variables:
#   .. ..$ NR    : chr [1:2] "GHP-0169" "GHP-0237"
# .. ..$ DATE  : chr [1:2] "14-09-2011" "30-06-2010"
# .. ..$ CODE  : chr [1:2] "1" "1"
# .. ..$ DATE2 : chr [1:2] "14-09-2011" "05-01-2012"
# .. ..$ type  : chr [1:2] "50.37" "50.37"
# .. ..$ center: chr [1:2] "GHP" "GHP"
# ..$ NNB:Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  6 variables:
#   .. ..$ NR    : chr [1:5] "NNB-0243" "NNB-0303" "NNB-0306" "NNB-0359" ...
# .. ..$ DATE  : chr [1:5] "16-05-2016" "04-07-2012" "11-07-2012" "05-12-2012" ...
# .. ..$ CODE  : chr [1:5] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
# .. ..$ DATE2 : chr [1:5] "11-05-2016" "05-07-2012" "11-07-2012" "06-12-2012" ...
# .. ..$ type  : chr [1:5] "YY.90.00" "50.37" "YY.50.01" "YY.82.01" ...
# .. ..$ center: chr [1:5] "NNB" "NNB" "NNB" "NNB" ...
# $ df2:List of 3
# ..$ DBD:Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  6 variables:
#   .. ..$ NR    : chr [1:3] "DBD-0006" "DBD-0057" "DBD-0095"
# .. ..$ DATE  : chr [1:3] "13-07-2011" "15-12-2010" "09-03-2011"
# .. ..$ CODE  : chr [1:3] "1" "1" "1"
# .. ..$ DATE2 : chr [1:3] "18-07-2011" "15-12-2010" "09-03-2011"
# .. ..$ type  : chr [1:3] "YY.90.01" "50.19" "50.37"
# .. ..$ center: chr [1:3] "DBD" "DBD" "DBD"
# ..$ GHP:Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 2 obs. of  6 variables:
#   .. ..$ NR    : chr [1:2] "GHP-0169" "GHP-0237"
# .. ..$ DATE  : chr [1:2] "14-09-2011" "30-06-2010"
# .. ..$ CODE  : chr [1:2] "1" "1"
# .. ..$ DATE2 : chr [1:2] "14-09-2011" "05-01-2012"
# .. ..$ type  : chr [1:2] "50.37" "50.37"
# .. ..$ center: chr [1:2] "GHP" "GHP"
# ..$ NNB:Classes ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  6 variables:
#   .. ..$ NR    : chr [1:5] "NNB-0243" "NNB-0303" "NNB-0306" "NNB-0359" ...
# .. ..$ DATE  : chr [1:5] "16-05-2016" "04-07-2012" "11-07-2012" "05-12-2012" ...
# .. ..$ CODE  : chr [1:5] "1" "1" "1" "1" ...
# .. ..$ DATE2 : chr [1:5] "11-05-2016" "05-07-2012" "11-07-2012" "06-12-2012" ...
# .. ..$ type  : chr [1:5] "YY.90.00" "50.37" "YY.50.01" "YY.82.01" ...
# .. ..$ center: chr [1:5] "NNB" "NNB" "NNB" "NNB" ...
```

Note, that I use just two data frames to not bloat the answer too much. If you really need the data frames in your workspace you can do `list2env(res, .GlobalEnv)`, but better keep it in the list.

---

*Data:*

```
df1 <- df2 <- structure(list(NR = c("DBD-0006", "DBD-0057", "DBD-0095", "GHP-0169", 
"GHP-0237", "NNB-0243", "NNB-0303", "NNB-0306", "NNB-0359", "NNB-0364"
), DATE = c("13-07-2011", "15-12-2010", "09-03-2011", "14-09-2011", 
"30-06-2010", "16-05-2016", "04-07-2012", "11-07-2012", "05-12-2012", 
"12-12-2012"), CODE = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1"), DATE2 = c("18-07-2011", "15-12-2010", "09-03-2011", 
"14-09-2011", "05-01-2012", "11-05-2016", "05-07-2012", "11-07-2012", 
"06-12-2012", "12-12-2012"), type = c("YY.90.01", "50.19", "50.37", 
"50.37", "50.37", "YY.90.00", "50.37", "YY.50.01", "YY.82.01", 
"YY.50.02"), center = c("DBD", "DBD", "DBD", "GHP", "GHP", "NNB", 
"NNB", "NNB", "NNB", "NNB")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Wonderful! I did not know about the split function. It is really useful. Could you also help me with one more thing please? I added the center column to all the three dataframes myself. Now, before extracting the split files I need to remove them. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use 1:5 columns as subset `lapply(cnt, \(x) split(x[1:5], x$center))` or safer `lapply(cnt, \(x) split(x[c("NR", "DATE", "CODE", "DATE2", "type"), x$center))`.

Comment: As I have different variables in each of the three dfs, is it possible to somehow only deselect center?

Comment: @Rara Sure, use `setdiff`. `lapply(cnt, \(x) split(x[setdiff(names(x), 'center')], x$center))`.

Answer (score 0):

Below is one way to make your `for` loop approach work. Note that I slightly altered the filter criterium to actually show that it is working. My understanding is that you want to keep only rows which are either "DBD", "GHP" or "MNB", correct?

```r
library(dplyr)

output <- list ()    

for (table in names(cnt)) {                  #print(table)  df1, df2, df3
  for (name in names(cnt[[table]])) {          #print(name)  returns the variable names per df
    center_name <- c("DBD", "GHP")# left "NNB" out to test 
    output[[table]] <- filter(cnt[[table]], center %in% center_name)     
  }
}

output
#> $df1
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   NR       DATE       CODE  DATE2      type     center
#>   <chr>    <chr>      <chr> <chr>      <chr>    <chr> 
#> 1 DBD-0006 13-07-2011 1     18-07-2011 YY.90.01 DBD   
#> 2 DBD-0057 15-12-2010 1     15-12-2010 50.19    DBD   
#> 3 DBD-0095 09-03-2011 1     09-03-2011 50.37    DBD   
#> 4 GHP-0169 14-09-2011 1     14-09-2011 50.37    GHP   
#> 5 GHP-0237 30-06-2010 1     05-01-2012 50.37    GHP   
#> 
#> $df2
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   NR       DATE       CODE  DATE2      type     center
#>   <chr>    <chr>      <chr> <chr>      <chr>    <chr> 
#> 1 DBD-0006 13-07-2011 1     18-07-2011 YY.90.01 DBD   
#> 2 DBD-0057 15-12-2010 1     15-12-2010 50.19    DBD   
#> 3 DBD-0095 09-03-2011 1     09-03-2011 50.37    DBD   
#> 4 GHP-0169 14-09-2011 1     14-09-2011 50.37    GHP   
#> 5 GHP-0237 30-06-2010 1     05-01-2012 50.37    GHP   
#> 
#> $df3
#> # A tibble: 5 × 6
#>   NR       DATE       CODE  DATE2      type     center
#>   <chr>    <chr>      <chr> <chr>      <chr>    <chr> 
#> 1 DBD-0006 13-07-2011 1     18-07-2011 YY.90.01 DBD   
#> 2 DBD-0057 15-12-2010 1     15-12-2010 50.19    DBD   
#> 3 DBD-0095 09-03-2011 1     09-03-2011 50.37    DBD   
#> 4 GHP-0169 14-09-2011 1     14-09-2011 50.37    GHP   
#> 5 GHP-0237 30-06-2010 1     05-01-2012 50.37    GHP
```

A less verbose way to achieve the same outcome can be achieved using `purrr::map`:

```r
library(purrr)
center_name <- c("DBD", "GHP") # left "NNB" out to test 

cnt %>% 
  map(\(x) filter(x,  center %in% center_name))
```

Data from OP

```
dat1 <- structure(list(NR = c("DBD-0006", "DBD-0057", 
                      "DBD-0095", "GHP-0169", "GHP-0237", "NNB-0243", "NNB-0303", 
                      "NNB-0306", "NNB-0359", "NNB-0364"), DATE = c("13-07-2011", 
                                                                    "15-12-2010", "09-03-2011", "14-09-2011", "30-06-2010", "16-05-2016", 
                                                                    "04-07-2012", "11-07-2012", "05-12-2012", "12-12-2012"), CODE= c("1", 
                                                                                                                                     "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1"), DATE2 = c("18-07-2011", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "15-12-2010", "09-03-2011", "14-09-2011", "05-01-2012", "11-05-2016", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "05-07-2012", "11-07-2012", "06-12-2012", "12-12-2012"), type = c("YY.90.01", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "50.19", "50.37", "50.37", "50.37", "YY.90.00", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               "50.37", "YY.50.01", "YY.82.01", "YY.50.02"), center = c("DBD", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "DBD", "DBD", "GHP", "GHP", "NNB", "NNB", "NNB", "NNB", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "NNB")), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    "data.frame"))

dat2 <- dat3 <- dat1

cnt <- list(df1 = dat1,
            df2 = dat2,
            df3 = dat3)
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-28 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry if my question was not clear enough. What I wanted was to split the data based on the center. The solution that jay.sf has proposed does exactly what I need. Still I am disappointed that I can never write a working for loop. If you can show me what I did wrong I would really appreciate it.